# mysql - select newest value of groups by date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

I have a table, member_track, that tracks website visits from members. From the looks of it, it tracks every load.

I need to produce a result set of just the newest visit from *each* member.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
member_id   last_accessed
    1413        2015-5-26  8:57
    1413        2015-5-26  8:54
    1413        2015-5-26  8:50
    1413        2015-5-26  8:48
    1413        2015-5-26  8:20
    1413        2015-5-26  8:17
    1412        2015-4-30  7:34
    1412        2015-4-30  7:33
    1411        2015-4-18  15:51
    1411        2015-4-18  15:50
```

The output would need to be:

```
member_id   last_accessed
    1413        2015-5-26  8:57
    1412        2015-4-30  7:34
    1411        2015-4-18  15:51
```

(`last_accessed` is a `datetime` field)

I have tried various things with group by and max, but am not having any success. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to query `max(last_accessed)` per (i.e., grouped by) `member_id`:

```
SELECT   member_id, max(last_accessed)
FROM     member_track
GROUP BY member_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can try out the following Query.

```
SELECT member_id,last_accessed
  FROM member_track
 WHERE last_accessed in(
     SELECT Max(last_accessed)
       FROM member_track
     GROUP BY member_id)
```